# What is an invariant Simplex

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, vector-fields, simplex, invariance

Let $$\Delta=\{x_i\in\mathbb{R}^k_+: \sum_{i=1}^kx_i=1\}$$ where k is a positive integer. I've read in a book the following:

> The simplex $\Delta \subset \mathbb{R}^k$ can be shown to be *invariant* in this dynamics.

I would like to know: What does it mean an invariant simplex (math definition)?
and, given this dynamics, how can we prove that a simplex is invariant (an example will answer my question :))?

Comment: what dynamics is this?

Comment: This is for the Replicator dynamics equation used in EGT (Evolutionary Game Theory). here is the equation, $\partial x_i/\partial t = u(e^i-x,x)*x_i$ where $x \in \Delta$ and $e^i$ is a vector of the form $(0,...,1,0,...,0)$, 1 at index i and 0 otherwise.

Comment: ok, maybe means that if $\sum_i x_i=1$ then $\sum_i\frac{\partial x_i}{\partial t}=1$

Comment: $\sum_{i=1}^k \partial x_i/\partial t$ must be $1$, since x is a probability distribution. Maybe u r right, I'll keep looking. Thx.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, the *invariant simplex* means that (in this case) *standard simplex* is *invariant* with respect to some dynamical system. The *standard simplex* is an object given by 
$$\Delta=\{x_i\in\mathbb{R}^k_+: \sum_{i=1}^kx_i=1\}. $$

It is *invariant* with respect to some dynamical system if all trajectories with initial condition at $\Delta$ stay at $\Delta$ for all time. If you have a vector field given by system of ODEs $\dot{\mathbf{x}} = V(\mathbf{x})$, then *standard simplex* is *invariant* iff for all $\mathbf{x} \in \Delta$  holds
$$ (V(\mathbf{x}), \mathbf{1}) = 0, $$
where $\mathbf{1}$ denotes vector $(1, 1, \dots, 1)$. This condition is what we get if we apply [Bony-Brezis theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bony%E2%80%93Brezis_theorem) to $\Delta$ and system
$\dot{\mathbf{x}} = V(\mathbf{x})$.

Comment: Thank you, That's what I was looking for :).